# speed lines drawing for 100 000 points

Tags: c++, performance, graphics, qt5

I want to draw ~300 poly-lines, with ~300 points in each one.
And according to my measuring it takes ~50ms on not bad notebook (linux/qt 5.11/i7/16GB/nvidia gpu).

Is any way to improve drawing speed?
I create simple example to reproduce my problem,
in real program I get points on-the-fly,
so I can do any `QPixmap` caching or so on things.
This example prints:

> number of regions:  304
>      min  44 , max  1808 , avg  301
>      time of work:  54  ms

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QFile>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QWidget>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>

class MyW final : public QWidget {
public:
  MyW(QVector<QVector<QPoint>> &lines) : lines_(lines) {}
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
    QElapsedTimer work_timer;
    work_timer.start();

    QPainter painter{this};
    painter.fillRect(rect(), Qt::gray);
    painter.setPen(QPen{Qt::red, 8});
    for (const QVector<QPoint> &item : lines_) {
      painter.drawPolyline(&item[0], item.size());
    }
    qInfo() << "time of work: " << work_timer.elapsed() << " ms";
  }

private:
  QVector<QVector<QPoint>> lines_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QVector<QVector<QPoint>> lines;
  {
    QFile f("/tmp/data.txt");
    f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    assert(f.isOpen());
    QDataStream d(&f);
    d >> lines;
    assert(!lines.empty());
    qInfo() << "number of regions: " << lines.size();

    int min = lines[0].size(), max = lines[0].size();
    double avg = 0.;
    for (const QVector<QPoint> &item : lines) {
      min = std::min(item.size(), min);
      max = std::max(item.size(), max);
      avg += item.size();
    }
    qInfo() << "min " << min << ", max " << max << ", avg "
            << std::round(avg / lines.size());
  }
  MyW w{lines};
  w.showMaximized();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: "Is any way to improve drawing speed?" Use OpenGL/DirectX.

Comment: @Swordfish But it is rather strange for me, is 100k points is limit for cpu rendering on current hardware?

Comment: its limited by Qt and WinAPI.

Comment: I suppose another approach would be to break up the list of lines into N subsets (where N is the number of cores on the computer), hand each subset to a different thread to have that thread draw it into a QImage, then combine the resulting QImages back together (using alpha channel) into a QPixmap to render on the screen.   Whether that would actually be faster is an open question, though.

Comment: In the code shown the data in `MyW::lines`, having been initialized, never changes.  Is that always the case for the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @G.M. No, lines alwawys recalculated on the fly, it is just for this toy example for slow drawing problem investigation.